# Dot Zero call to timer in Rust/Bevy?

Tags: rust, bevy

In the Bevy book the following code is used:

```
struct GreetTimer(Timer);

fn greet_people(
    time: Res<Time>, mut timer: ResMut<GreetTimer>, query: Query<&Name, With<Person>>) {
    // update our timer with the time elapsed since the last update
    // if that caused the timer to finish, we say hello to everyone
    if timer.0.tick(time.delta()).just_finished() {
        for name in query.iter() {
            println!("hello {}!", name.0);
        }
    }
}
```

What are the `timer.0` and `name.0` calls doing? The book doesn't address it, and I see that `Timer` has a [tick](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.3.0/bevy/prelude/struct.Timer.html#method.tick) method, so what is `.0` doing here since `timer` is already a `Timer`?

Comment: But you're using `GreetTimer`, not `Timer`. And GreetTimer is a [tuple struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#using-tuple-structs-without-named-fields-to-create-different-types), so you have to access its first (and only) element, as `GreetTimer` itself does not define a `tick()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is related to tuples. In rust tuples can be accessed by item position in that way:

```rust
let foo: (u32, u32) = (0, 1);
println!("{}", foo.0);
println!("{}", foo.1);
```

It also happens with some (tuple) structs:

```
struct Foo(u32);

let foo = Foo(1);
println!("{}", foo.0);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=20122eec453f91a283f631446a6bee98)

You can further check some [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#using-tuple-structs-without-named-fields-to-create-different-types).

Comment: So `ResMut<GreetTimer>` is a 1-tuple of `GreetTimer` or the ResMut struct can be operated upon as if it were a tuple?

Comment: @BWStearns, GreetTimer is a wrapper type, which its solely inner element is accessed with that `.0`

Comment: `ResMut` [implements](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.5.0/bevy/prelude/struct.ResMut.html#trait-implementations) `Deref` / `DerefMut`, that's why you can magically operate on `ResMut<T>` as if it were a `T` ([see book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html)). `.0` is an artifact of `GreetTimer` being a tuple struct, and is a separate concern from `ResMut` being automatically dereferenced by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful!